# react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.jsxDEV(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I created a react-redux project and I used json-server as a server. when I create an order, I save  status in state in UiReducer and use it in "OrderStatusPage". The NODE_ENV is set to "development". The order is added to my db.json but I got this error in "OrderStatusPage":

Uncaught TypeError: react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.jsxDEV(...) is not a function

how can I solve this error? Thanks a lot.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
export const OrderStatusPage = () => {
const notification = useSelector((state) => state.ui.notification);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-md-6 my-5 text-center">
          {notification &&
          (<Notification
            title={notification.title}
            message={notification.message}
            status={notification.status}
          />)(notification.status === "success") ? (
            <Button type="button" >
              Go to your Order
            </Button>
          ) : (
            <Button type="button" >
              Go to your Cart
            </Button>
          )} 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think everything is fine. Maybe you just need split the two conditions you have like this:

```
{notification &&
      (<Notification
        title={notification.title}
        message={notification.message}
        status={notification.status}
      />)}
{notification.status === "success" ? (
        <Button type="button" >
          Go to your Order
        </Button>
      ) : (
        <Button type="button" >
          Go to your Cart
        </Button>
      )}
```

I think this will work.

Comment: Thanks, this works and I also have another problem in uiReducer and I solve that. Finally it 's ok now.

Comment: I am glad to hear that ^-^

Answer (score 0):

You should not change the state directly.
Try useState like:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
export const OrderStatusPage = () => {
const [uistate, setUistate]=React.useState()
React.useEffect(()=>{
setUistate(useSelector((state) => state.ui.notification));
},[])

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-md-6 my-5 text-center">
          {uistate &&
          (<Notification
            title={uistate.title}
            message={uistate.message}
            status={uistate.status}
          />)(uistate.status === "success") ? (
            <Button type="button" >
              Go to your Order
            </Button>
          ) : (
            <Button type="button" >
              Go to your Cart
            </Button>
          )} 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I know this and I manage my state with redux and not with useState.

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you are using the `Notification` and `Button` components but not importing these components.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Notification } from "./Notification";
import { Button } from "./Button";

export const OrderStatusPage = () => {
  const notification = useSelector((state) => state.ui.notification);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-md-6 my-5 text-center">
          {notification && (
            <Notification
              title={notification.title}
              message={notification.message}
              status={notification.status}
            />
          )}
          {notification.status === "success" ? (
            <Button type="button">Go to your Order</Button>
          ) : (
            <Button type="button">Go to your Cart</Button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I just removed them in stackoverflow to decrease the lines of code.